# magento product layout update xml setData not working

Tags: xml, magento, variables, product

In my update XML I have:

```
<reference name="content">
 <remove name="product.info" />
 <block type="catalog/product_view" template="catalog/product/imageview.phtml">
<action method="setData"><name>variable</name><value>3</value></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

I have created imageview.phtml and it is loaded correctly. In this template I dump the following:

```
var_dump($this->getVariable());
```

My expected result is: 3

But the result is: NULL

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the key name `variable` or something else? Maybe the method you are calling exists and returns `null`?

Answer (score 5):

Old question I know but I came across the same issue this morning. Hopefully it might save someone else some time.

Your block needs a name for it to accept any variables via the setData method.

**Example**:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product_image_view" template="catalog/product/imageview.phtml">
   <action method="setData"><name>variable</name><value>3</value></action>
</block>
```

Not sure why it requires a name as it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere. Might be worth adding an `alais="product_image_view"` too to avoid any further *Magentoism*'s

Comment: What if you want to pass the result of a product method?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the key a different name?

```
<action method="setData">
   <name>my_variable</name>
   <value>3</value>
</action>
```

And call it like so

```
echo $this->getMyVariable();
```